# Displaying an Atalasoft Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, viewer

I have an AtalaImage class loaded with a TIFF image instance and I want to display the image in a WPF AtalaImageViewer control or even the stock standard .Net WPF Image control.

It should be simply but I can't figure out how to do this, can someone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to copy Atalasoft binary to MemoryStream and read with BitmapSource class.

Something like this. (I have not tested)

```
    var atalaIamge = new AtalaImage(100, 100, PixelFormat.Pixel32bppBgra);

    var imageData = atalaIamge.ToByteArray(new PngEncoder())
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        mem.Position = 0;
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.UriSource = null;
        image.StreamSource = mem;
        image.EndInit();
    }

    wpfImageControl.Source = image;
```